# Want to drag a div through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am trying to use the jquery UI draggable option `handle`, but not working, i tried :

```
      $("div").draggable( { handle : $("#buttonid") })
```

Can anyody tell me the problem?

**Edit**

The handle is not actually working as a handle, means i want to drag `handle` to drag div, but it is not working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("div").draggable( { 
         handle : "#buttonid"  // you need not to wrap with $()
       });
```

---

#### According to your edit

> I haven't tested this. As Button's default `event-handler` for
>   `mousedown`. You might want to try with
>   `event.preventDefault()` inside a `mousedown` handler or alternatively
>   wrap that button with a `span` or `div` and make that `div` or `span`
>   as handler, But I think none of them will work.

For more look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875063/draggable-button-using-jquery)**