# How to use jQuery draggable with Bower?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, bower

I installed jquery-ui-draggable with bower but it doesn't work. Items are not draggable.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery-ui-draggable/dist/jquery-ui-draggable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Draggable Test</h2>
    <br>
    <button id="dragbtn">Drag me</button>
</body>
```

Script.js

```
$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#dragbtn').draggable();
    });
})
```

Comment: I think, you need to install jQuery UI as well.

Comment: I believe, bower downloads the component's dependencies. You need to refer those here in HTML

Comment: @Navaneeth I installed jquery-ui but still doesn't work. I updated the question.

Comment: Is it showing any error in the console?

Comment: @Navaneeth Nope. That is the problem that no errors at all. Maybe I reference to wrong packages?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875063/draggable-button-using-jquery-ui

Probably, you would need prevent default or simple make it a div rather than button

Comment: @Navaneeth that worked. I canged the code .draggable({cancel:false}) .

Comment: [jquery-ui-draggable](https://github.com/hey-red/jquery-ui-draggable) is someone's old custom build. It may or may not work with newer versions. Just remove it and include official jquery ui installed via `bower install jquery-ui`.

Comment: @TJ Thanks for your answer I made it working with ui-draggable. I put the solution in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$( "#dragbtn" ).draggable({
        cancel: false
    });
```

Comment: It's always better to add an explanation to the code you're posting as an answer, so that it will helps visitors understand why this is a good answer.